# Complex manifold defined over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a connected closed complex manifold with an antiholomorphic involution.

Must there be an atlas and a choice of a reference point in each chart such that the transition functions are ratios of holomorphic functions each having Taylor series with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Closely related to your previous question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373095/complex-projective-manifold-with-an-antiholomorphic-involution, which if I understand correctly covers the projective case.

Comment: Not really a counterexample, but still. Take a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$ without real points, by base change to $\mathbb{C}$ you get a non-standard antiholomorphic involution on $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ without fixed points. Obviously $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ does descend to a real manifold, but this has nothing to do with the given involution.

Comment: @GiulioBresciani I am not sure I understand you. Both of those curves are real models of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ and provide an atlas as in the question. The presence of real points is not essential.

Comment: @JoeT Sorry, my fault!

Comment: @JoeT:  I noticed that you have now changed the question completely.  You should at least admit that I gave a correct solution to the original question.

Comment: @JoeT Indeed, I would recommend reverting this back to the original question, accepting Robert's answer, and posing this new question as a distinct question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trivial construction that shows that the answer is 'yes' for all complex manifolds, not just those that admit an anti-holomorphic involution.

Let $(M,J)$ be a (finite-dimensional) complex $n$-manifold and let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $M$ with the properties that *(i)* for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$, there is a $J$-holomorphic chart $\zeta:U\to\mathbb{C}^n$, and *(ii)* For each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there is a point $p\in U$ that does not lie in any $V\in\mathscr{U}$ other than $U$. (Using paracompactness, it is not difficult to construct such a chart.) Then by choosing one such 'reference point' $p_U\in U$ with $p_U\not\in V\in\mathscr{U}$ for $V\not=U$ and  one $J$-holomorphic chart $\zeta_U:U\to\mathbb{C}^n$ so that $\zeta_U(p_U) = 0\in\mathbb{C}^n$, we arrive at a 'pointed atlas'
$$
\widehat{\mathscr{U}} = \{ (U,\zeta_U,p_U)\ |\ U\in \mathscr{U}\ \}
$$
with all the stated properties.  The reason is that the only time the point $p_U$ is in the domain of a transition function for the pointed atlas $
\widehat{\mathscr{U}}$ is when one is 'transitioning' from $U$ to $V=U$, and, in that case, the only transition function is the identity mapping on $\zeta_U(U)\subset\mathbb{C}^n$, whose Taylor series at $\zeta_U(p_U) = 0\in\mathbb{C}^n$ clearly has all coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ (in fact, all the coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Note that this answer is a correct answer to the original question, which, I admit, was badly posed.

Comment: Moderators have turned back to the original question, which is the one answer here.

Comment: As currently worded, the question asks about "transition functions". These are functions $\zeta_U\circ\zeta_V^{-1}:\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$  defined on the "transition" $U\cap V$ that move from one chart to another. This answer makes no mention of the transition functions, only the charts.  But perhaps the original wording of the question failed to say "transition" !?

Comment: @Linas:  I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.  Also, I'm not sure that you have read the answer since, contrary to what you claim, I explicitly talk about the transition functions in the last sentence.

Comment: I read the question as asking "for all transitions $U\cap V$ ..." and I don't understand how your answer implies that $\zeta_U \circ\zeta_V^{-1}$ is meromorphic with coefficients in $\mathbb {R}$ (for all pairs $U$, $V$).

Comment: @Linas: You may have missed the point of the question. The OP originally wanted the transition functions of the atlas to have the property that their Taylor series *at every point* had coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. When it was pointed out that this is impossible, the OP modified the question to require only that the Taylor series at a specified 'reference point' in each chart have coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.  I showed, in my answer, that there is such a 'real pointed atlas' for *any* complex manifold.  In other words, it wasn't a useful notion.  The OP then changed the question completely.

Comment: @RobertBryant OK, thank you! Clearly, I've layered my own muddled thinking on top of a muddled situation. I'm now embarrassed by my own earlier questions, which I'm sorely tempted to delete because they're just ... wrong. Blame it on late-night cross-eyed bleariness.